# how to switch from posix to windows with cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin

im writing a python script that is being executed in cygwin.  one of the things its doing is calling pg_dump and passing it a file name.  my problem, python/cygwin is passing it a posix path and the windows version of pg_dump doesn't know what to do with it.  is there something that i can call to convert my posix path to a windows path?

i want to convert this path

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/me/Code/myproj/pyBuildScript/src/snapshooter/working/sso.sql
```

to

```
c:\Users\me\Code\myproj\pyBuildScript\src\snapshooter\working\sso.sql
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cygpath -w
```

You can read the manual page for more switches. Among them

- -w for windows
- -u for unix
- -a for absolute path

You need to be careful with escaping, make sure the path argument is a single shell word.

Comment: so, i run cygpath before my script?

Comment: Yes, like: `your_program_here.py "$(cygpath -w "$P")"`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
>>> posix_str = "/cygdrive/c/Users/me/Code/myproj/pyBuildScript/src/snapshooter/working/sso.sql"
>>> nt_str = "C:" + posix_str[11:]
>>> nt_str = nt_str.replace("/", "\\")
>>> print nt_str
C:\Users\me\Code\myproj\pyBuildScript\src\snapshooter\working\sso.sql
```